# Utilizar variavel temporaria no MySQL (select)

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de utilizar a variavel `saldo` na consulta logo após o `WHERE` onde temos `c2.veiculo_horimetro_proxima_revisao-c3.veiculo_horimetro`. Quando eu tento utilizar, retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'saldo' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT
    c1.id_ativo_veiculo,
    c1.id_interno_maquina,
    c1.veiculo,
    c1.marca,
    c1.modelo,
    c1.ano,
    c2.veiculo_custo,
    c2.id_ativo_veiculo_manutencao,
    max(c2.veiculo_horimetro_proxima_revisao) as veiculo_horimetro_proxima_revisao,
    max(c3.veiculo_horimetro) as veiculo_horimetro_atual,
    (max(c2.veiculo_horimetro_proxima_revisao)-max(c3.veiculo_horimetro)) as saldo,
    c4.operacao_alerta
FROM
    ativo_veiculo AS c1
    JOIN ativo_veiculo_manutencao AS c2 ON c2.id_ativo_veiculo = c1.id_ativo_veiculo    
    INNER JOIN ativo_veiculo_operacao AS c3 ON c3.id_ativo_veiculo=c1.id_ativo_veiculo
    JOIN configuracao AS c4 ON c4.id_configuracao=1
WHERE
    c1.tipo_veiculo = 'maquina'
    AND (c2.veiculo_horimetro_proxima_revisao-c3.veiculo_horimetro) <= c4.operacao_alerta
    AND (c2.veiculo_horimetro_proxima_revisao-c3.veiculo_horimetro) > 0
GROUP BY c2.id_ativo_veiculo;

ORDER BY c2.id_ativo_veiculo_manutencao DESC
```

Como eu poderia utilizar o `saldo` para fazer a operação de subtração?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2):

A cláusula WHERE não permite utilizar alias.
Em MySQL podes usar a cláusula HAVING, que é executada depois da agregação.

```
HAVING saldo >= c4.operação_alerta
```